# Bootstrap DatetimePicker Selector Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am using [eonasdan's bootstrap 3 datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). I just wanted to know is it possible open the selector using the input field as well as the calendar glyphicon.

I know how to make it open using either the input field or the glyphicon but not both.

HTML is below:

```
<div class='input-group date'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1'>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      format: 'ddd D MMMM, YYYY'
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a function `allowInputToggle` to open datepicker while clicking on both icon and input, which you can find [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#allowinputtoggle)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        format: 'ddd D MMMM, YYYY',
        allowInputToggle: true
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br>
<div class='col-sm-6'>
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
   <input type='text' class="form-control" />
   <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Shehary this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot, I will accept as answer.

Comment: I added allowInputToggle but mine is still not working at the moment.

Comment: move the `id='datetimepicker1` from input to `<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>`

Comment: function `allowInputToggle` support `v4.7.14` and above, not sure which version you are using but you can find all versions here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datetimepicker and yes function `allowInputToggle` not supported `v4.0.0` and below

Comment: I was using an older version like I thought. It is working now exactly like in your demo. Thanks so much for your help.